# How to stringfy projection properties in Java?

Tags: java, json, spring, object, projection

I fill the following projection by joining two tables and it returns only a single record:

```
public interface EmployeeProjection {

    UUID getEmployeeUuid();

    String getEmployeeName();

    UUID getCompanyUuid();

    String getCompanyName();
}
```

I want to return this single record in `EmployeeProjection` type to my QR Code and for this reason I want to convert this data to an array or JSON. So, how can I manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jackson API which I recommend to implement it.

```
EmployeeProjection obj = new EmployeeProjection();
StringWriter jsonString = new StringWriter();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writeValue(jsonString, obj);
System.out.println("Employee JSON is: " + jsonString);
```

This is the output.

```
{"EmployeeUuid":"1","EmployeeName":"John" ... }
```

This is the library.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Further process:

```
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jp = jsonFactory.createJsonParser(jsonString.toString());
jp.setCodec(new ObjectMapper());
JsonNode jsonNode = jp.readValueAsTree();
// loop through json node
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = jsonNode.fields();
while (fields.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = fields.next();
    // Output key and text value
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue().textValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any way without using a library? On the other hand, will the generated data format is suitable for QR Code data? I am trying to build something like: `EmployeeUuid: 1   EmployeeName: John   CompanyUuid: 100   CompanyName: Siemens`.

Comment: **1.** Thanks a lot amigo, I tried and it gives result in JSON format. Maybe it is good so that after QR Code is read, this JSON data will be processed and formatted. So, there is no need to format it, am I wrong?

Comment: **2.** On the other hand, does it have format feature if I want to format the result e.g. one property on each line?

Comment: Amigo? Any reply pls?

Comment: to read json it does not to be formatted. Formatting the json introduces lots of whitespace characters which blow up your data volume. So you probably do not want it formatted to keep your QR code small.

Comment: @JensBaitinger You right, but what if I want to display just keys and values on separate lines except from "}" and "{" characters, etc? Should I write only JSON to the QR code as data in any case? Sorry, I am new in QR Code :(

Comment: You can further process the json string from my answer like split it by comma.

Comment: Json is with brackets... if you dont want the brackets, its no longer json. What do you want to do with the string in the QR Code? if you want to parse it, it might be easier to have it in a industry standard format (which JSON is).

Comment: @binary based on you want just keys and values on separate lines, I updated my answer for you.